# Trouble installing Heroku taps gem using RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, heroku, rvm

I tried to install the taps gem on my rvm, but got the following result:

```
larson:~ larson$ rvm gem install taps
Successfully installed taps-0.3.23
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for taps-0.3.23...
Installing RDoc documentation for taps-0.3.23...
larson:~ larson$ ruby -S gem which taps
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library taps
```

The strange thing is that taps still appears in my gem list. What does this error mean and will it prevent me from using Heroku's db:push commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem which` find the location of a **library** file in gems. There is no `taps.rb` in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/`, so you got the above message:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 27 10:31 taps
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 27 10:31 vendor
```

Another example with puppet:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.1/lib/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root 4096 Jul 18 16:41 puppet
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 3781 Jul 18 16:41 puppet.rb

# gem which puppet
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/puppet-2.7.1/lib/puppet
```

---

> So what command would you use to verify that the taps (or puppet) gem
>   is present and working?

```
gem list taps

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

taps (0.3.23)
```

and:

```
taps -h
Options
=======
server    Start a taps database import/export server
pull      Pull a database from a taps server
push      Push a database to a taps server
version   Taps version

Add '-h' to any command to see their usage
```

Comment: So what command would you use to verify that the taps (or puppet) gem is present and working?

Comment: Please check out my above answer.